# Объявить переменные из post запроса node js

Tags: node.js

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу объявить переменные которые приходят на сервер (node js) с помощью post запроса.
Сейчас использую данный код и получаю такое содержимое

```
name=Test&ip=192.168.0.1
```

Как я могу объявить переменную и присвоить ей значение что бы было так:

```
var name = "Test"; 
var ip = "192.168.0.1";
```

Код который использую:

```
var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function(request, response){
    if (request.method === 'POST') {
        let body = '';
        request.on('data', chunk => {
            body += chunk.toString(); // convert Buffer to string
        });
        request.on('end', () => {
            console.log(body);
        });
    }
    response.end()
}).listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я советую использовать express body-parser, и у вас будет объект request.body.
Oставляю ссылку для использования: https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser